# Why is that we cannot install native libraries on Expo? (that requires linking)

Tags: react-native

I am a newbie and learned react-native expo. I am curious why we can't use any native library with Expo.

For example, if I want to use filesystem on expo I just cant use it, I know expo has it's own file system but I want to use another library but that library requires linking so it is not working in expo. Why is that?

I have tried everything.

This is the library that I want to use ==> https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

It requires command : `react-native link react-native-fs`

How do I do it?

Comment: Hey @shery, It is unclear when you say that "I just cant use it" are you having trouble installing the lib or requiring it from a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to understand the difference between `react-native cli` & `expo`
Please read [this documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and)  to understand the difference

React Native `expo` uses their own servers to compile your javascript into java and return APK file as a complete APP, and that is the reason you do not need android SDKs or android studio environment on your PC when you are using expo

but when you are using `react-native cli` you do need the android studio environment such as SDKs, because when you are using `cli` , it compiles the code using that android studio sdk/environment that you made in your PC that is why you do not need a third party server like expo do.
and thats the reason you get android files right in your `react-native` project and due to which you can add native modules to it.

However you also have the option to use `expo-eject`, You can read more about expo-eject in [this documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)

Thank You!, Have a great day & welcome to stackoverflow community!.

Comment: woah that was quick, thanks for your time! 

i just got the full sory behind expo reading your answer, i didnt knew that it is using thirdparty server